# I need a good analogy to make sense of Class methods vs. instance methods

Tags: objective-c, class, object, methods, instance

Im getting fairly confused as the book im reading is delving into the NSNumber class and talks about all the  different methods you can call on it. I have a couple questions:

1.) Do you not have to call a typical alloc or init on foundation classes?

2.)in what cases would you use, say, numberWithChar: as opposed to initWithChar (i think this is the part that is messing me up the most, not really sure im groking this concept on the level i need to be, if you folks could break it down for me I think it would really help me get over this humper-roo.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Class/Instance Analogies

Classes are like blueprints for a type house. Instances are like actual houses. So you can only have one blueprint for a single type of house, but you can have multiple actual houses of the same type. Also, you can have multiple blueprints, and each blueprint describes a different type of house.

Another analogy you can use is that classes are like cookie cutters, and instances are like cookies made from a cookie cutter.

#### How It Applies To Objective-C

There is one "class object" for every class in your code. To refer to the class object, you just use the class name. **`alloc` is a class method that allocates a new instance** like so:

`MyWidget* w = [MyWidget alloc];`

However, `alloc` doesn't initialize the class, so none of the member variables will be set up. **`init` is an instance method** that will initialize a newly allocated instance. So to allocate and initialize a new instance, you do this:

`MyWidget* w = [[MyWidget alloc] init];`

Which is equivalent to this:

```
MyWidget* w = [MyWidget alloc]; //alloc is being called on the class
w = [w init]; //init is being called on the instance
```

Another common type of class method is a factory method like `numberWithChar:`. This is basically what `numberWithChar:` does:

```
+(NSNumber*) numberWithChar:(char)c;
{
    return [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithChar:c] autorelease];
}
```

The only real difference is that `numberWithChar:` returns an autoreleased object.

All objects must be allocated and initialized. That includes foundation classes.

Answer (score 3):

1) `alloc` and `init` need to be called virtually always. `numberWithChar` is a convenience method, which means it calls `alloc`, `init`, and `autorelease` for you and returns the autoreleased instance.

2) Since `numberWithChar` returns an autoreleased object, that means unless you retain it (or pass it to something like an `NSArray` which will `retain` it), it'll be destroyed shortly. `initWithChar` returns a `retain`-ed object, which means you have to release it when you're done with it.

I found when I was starting out that it was helpful to use `init`-`alloc` as a rule, instead of the convenience methods, because it made me pay close attention to my memory management.

The difference between class and instance methods is addressed from a number of angles in the answers to this question [What is the difference between class and instance methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)

EDIT:

To be honest, the analogy I use when I call a class method on, say `NSString`, is praying to the god of NSStrings to bestow upon me a magnificent new `NSString`. Notice that class methods are almost 100% used for creation. e.g. `alloc` is a class method, `stringWithFormat` is a class method, and so on.

Yes, it's ridiculous, I know.

Comment: that's helpful, Is there anything else that helped you understand how class and instance methods differed when you first started? Appreciate the help. Nick

Comment: ...added my ridiculous analogy.. hope it helps :D

Comment: no no, you pray to the god of NSStrings to give you an instance. Once you have the instance you can just send messages to it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first thing:  In Objective-C, you don't *call a method*, you *send a message* to an object.  The runtime looks up the methods and calls them.

It might help you to think of a class as a factory. In fact, years ago, we used to refer to class methods as factory methods.