# Difference between Obj-C object and instance?

Tags: objective-c, oop, object, programming-languages, instance

I am learning Objective-C and I don't really understand the difference between an instance and an object. They commonly use both terms. Also, why is the alloc method applied to the class and the init method applied to the object?

Comment: Related: [class methods vs instance methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032538/i-need-a-good-analogy-to-make-sense-of-class-methods-vs-instance-methods)

Answer (score 7):

An instance is the same as an object, hence why both terms are used and can be used interchangeably — an instance of `NSString`, or an `NSString` object.

`+alloc` is a class method responsible for allocating the memory needed to store a new instance/object, and zeroing-out that memory. It returns a newly created instance/object.

`-init`, on the other hand, is responsible for further initialising this new instance;<sup>1</sup> for example, assigning default values to instance variables. Since `-init` operates on an existing instance, it’s an instance method.

<sup><sup>1</sup>In some cases `-init` might return an instance different from the one created by `+alloc`.</sup>

Comment: Note that a class is also an instance of its meta-class and meta-classes are also objects.