# +(void) or -(void) difference?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Objective-C: Class vs Instance Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)
>   [What do the plus and minus signs mean in Objective C next to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097294/what-do-the-plus-and-minus-signs-mean-in-objective-c-next-to-a-method)

I've tried to look around and couldn't come up with a solid answer that really explained my confusion. I've seen a few times and that is a class having a method that has it's "method type" set to "+" ie:
`-(Fraction*) fractionWithNumerator: (int) n denominator: (int) d;`

now how is that different to 
`+(Fraction*) fractionWithNumerator: (int) n denominator: (int) d;`

Comment: See [What do the plus and minus signs mean in Objective C next to a method? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097294/what-do-the-plus-and-minus-signs-mean-in-objective-c-next-to-a-method)

Comment: This one answered it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods

Answer (score 10):

"+" is a method called on the class.  "-" is a method called on an instance.

- +alloc: because you would say [NSString alloc]
- -init:  because you would call init on an instance rather than saying [NSString init]

Comment: All covered in the wonderful Objective-C documentation: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Answer (score 4):

The difference is one is a class method(+) and the other is an instance method(-).
[Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)