# What's the difference between -(void) and +(void) methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the plus and minus signs mean in Objective C next to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097294/what-do-the-plus-and-minus-signs-mean-in-objective-c-next-to-a-method)

Had an error which I fixed by changing -(void) to +(void), but I would like the understand it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This denotes an instance method.  You must hold a valid instance of the class to call this method.

```
-(void)
```

This denotes a class method.  You do not need an instance of the class to call this method.

```
+(void)
```

Answer (score 2):

**-** methods are **instance methods** and called on a specific instance of a class.

While **+** methods are **class methods** and called on the class itself.

Comment: problem with answering from an iPhone...by the time you peck out & proof your answer on the stupid wide text fields...someone else has done the same... **S.O. needs an iPhone version!**