# What is difference between -(NSMutableArray *)getContactsList and +(NSMutableArray *)getContactsList

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the plus and minus signs mean in Objective C next to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097294/what-do-the-plus-and-minus-signs-mean-in-objective-c-next-to-a-method)

I want to know the difference between the methods with - symbol and with +symbaol.

Ex.-(NSMutableArray *)getContactsList;
   +(NSMutableArray *)getContactsList;

Thanks
Praveena.

Comment: Same as [What do the plus and minus signs mean in Objective C next to a method?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097294/what-do-the-plus-and-minus-signs-mean-in-objective-c-next-to-a-method).

Comment: one is instance method and other is class method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two methods is;

The method which start with "-" is an instance method. you can call that method using the object of the specific class.

Ex:

```
A *a = [[A alloc] init];
array = [a getContactsList];
```

And The method which start with "+" is a Class method. you can call that method using class name.

Ex:

```
array = [A getContactsList];
```

That is the main difference.

And one more thing in the Class method you can use the Static variables only, instance variables.

Regards,

Satya.

Comment: Class methods can use statics or globals.  I'm assuming "private" and "normal" means instance variables? If so, then yes, but at least call 'em by their rightful name!

Answer (score -1):

The method with + is static method, which returns you a retained object, with an autorealease, it means you are not the owner of the object.

Comment: Objective-C does not have "static" methods; it has class methods.  Class methods are not guaranteed to return an autoreleased object (see `+new`).