# Objective-C: Class Level Function' meaning?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the plus and minus signs mean in Objective C next to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097294/what-do-the-plus-and-minus-signs-mean-in-objective-c-next-to-a-method)

I was confused between -(type) and +(type) in class.

```
@interface Class:Something{

    +(id) foo;
    -(void) fooAgain;
}
```

+(type) is class level function ( according to google)
but I don't understand the meaning of class level function.
Inside +(id)foo is kind of {return some value}
I think it is similar to getter or setter but somehow it must be different.
(because @property refers to getter/setter)

Can anybody explain simply? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Class methods* should be called using the **class name** itself. And, the *instance methods* should be called using **instances of the class**.

So, you have to call the above methods from some other classes, like the following,

*The class method*:

```
[Something foo]; // Correct
[Something fooAgain]; // Crash
```

*The instance method*:

```
Something *aThing = [[Something alloc] init];
[aThing fooAgain]; // Correct
[aThing foo]; // Crash
```