# what is different between - method and + method in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am new for the Objective C, though I am programming since last month, but I have never used + sign before the method definition. I have seen in other sample example but did not get any idea. Please help me, and provide me simple example if possible.
thanks

Comment: [What do the plus and minus signs mean in Objective-C next to a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097294/what-do-the-plus-and-minus-signs-mean-in-objective-c-next-to-a-method)

Answer (score 1):

Method `-` means it is an `instance` method, the `+` sign means it is a `class` method. See @lilius Caesar comment for the difference.

Comment: Oops, I deleted my comment before I noticed you'd referred to it. Here's that link again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089186/objective-c-difference-between-class-method-and-static-method/8089623#8089623