# What is the + implementation of methods? 

Tags: objective-c, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the plus and minus signs mean in Objective C next to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097294/what-do-the-plus-and-minus-signs-mean-in-objective-c-next-to-a-method)

Since I have started programming in Objective C, I have been implementing methods like this:

```
-(void)doSomething
```

Recently, I saw this in a piece of source code:

```
+(void)doSomething
```

What is the difference between the + and the - and what is the +?

Comment: Instance methods start with a -, class methods with a +

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods beginning with + are class methods; that is, they're not called on actual objects (instances of a class), but rather on a class itself.

Comment: So what is the difference if calling it on the class itself rather than the object?

Comment: @CoreCode you can't call the instance methods on the class.  You need an instance of the class in order to use those methods.

Comment: Instance methods are called on an object; that is, they can behave differently for each instance of the same class when the data structures' values in the two instances are different. But a class method will always do the same sort of thing (for the same arguments  given, and if no static variables related to that methods are modified) when called on one particular class.

Comment: @H2CO3 that last sentence is incorrect.  If the class method modifies a static field, you might not get the same results on every execution of the method, even with the same parameters.

Comment: Just for technical correctness, I'll point out that classes *are* "actual objects". They are instances of their metaclasses. In fact, that's really the meaning of a class method – it's an instance method of the class's metaclass. (Not that a newbie needs to know all this, but still.)

Comment: Yes, this is technically correct, however it is a speciality of Objective-C tha one can simply cast (Class) to (id) due to their similar memory layout (both structs begin with Class isa; (or metaclass). In most traditional OO languages, such as C", however, the classes are not instances, and class methods are called "static" methods.

Answer (score 0):

The methods with "+" before return type indicates that there are such an static methods (it exists without the instantiation of an object of that class). The methods with "-" are related to individual objects.

Comment: Typically Objective C programmers call them "class methods," not "static methods" as in Java.

Comment: Yeah, i know..but i'm say in an analogous way. In fact, class methods are the same as static methods like c#, java, c++, etc. ;-)