# Objective-C: What does "+(CCScene *)function { ... } mean?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the plus and minus signs mean in Objective C next to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097294/what-do-the-plus-and-minus-signs-mean-in-objective-c-next-to-a-method)

As I continue to learn about iOS, I came across this, `+(CCScene *)function {...}` in an early line of the example code I was working with. I understand that methods are implemented inObj-C with a `-`, as in the following method: `-(ObjectType*)function {...}`, but I am curious, what does the `+` that precedes the apparent function implementation indicate?

Comment: '+' indicate class method and '-' indicates instance method.

Comment: dup of [What do the plus and minus signs mean in Objective C next to a method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097294/what-do-the-plus-and-minus-signs-mean-in-objective-c-next-to-a-method)

Answer (score 2):

Instance methods (or rather messages in Objective-C) start with a `-`. Class methods start with a `+`. The difference is, that instance messages can be sent to objects of a certain class, while class messages has be sent to the class itself.

Let's say you have a class called Country. Then you might have an instance message `name` or `area`, which will return the name or the area of your Country instance.

```
NSString *name = [someCountry name];
// name could be "Germany" or "France" for instance.
```

You might also have a `numberOfCountries` class message, which will return the total number of Country instances.

```
int totalCount = [Country numberOfCountries];
```

Answer (score 1):

'+' indicates a class method and '-' indicates an instance method.  Thus, `+(CCScene *)function {...}` is a class method.

Instance methods operate on an object and has access to its instance variables, while a class method operates on a class as a whole and has no access to a particular instance's variables (unless you pass the instance in as a parameter).

For more information, see "[Class vs Instance Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053592/)" here on Stackoverflow.