# plus (+) versus minus (-) in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the plus and minus signs mean in Objective C next to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097294/what-do-the-plus-and-minus-signs-mean-in-objective-c-next-to-a-method)

What's the difference between using a plus or minus in Objective-C?

For example, most of the time code starts `-(void)somethingSomethingelse`, but sometimes it will be `+(void)somethingSomethingelse`

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In short, (+) is a class method and (-) is an instance method

See this answer for a full explanation
[What is the difference between class and instance methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)

Answer (score 36):

`-` functions are instance functions and `+` functions are class (static) functions.

So let's say you have a class called `Person`, and the following functions

`-(void)doSomething;`

`+(void)doSomethingElse;`

You would invoke these functions with the following:

`Person *myPerson = [[Person alloc] init];`

`[myPerson doSomething];`

`[Person doSomethingElse];`

This is more of a syntax description, assuming you understand the concept of class vs instance.

**edit:**

just to add: In objective-C, you can actually invoke a class function on an instance, but the effect is no different than invoking it on the class itself (essentially compiles to the same thing).

So you can do

`[myPerson doSomethingElse]`

Generally, you wouldn't do this as it is confusing and misleading to read. I am pointing it out so you won't be surprised if you come across code like this somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

member and public functions respectively.

Such that

```
id object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
+ (id)alloc;
- (id)init;
```

Where NSObject is a Class and id is an object

If you have ever used C++, a + is equivalent to static