# Class method successfully called instance method

Tags: objective-c, singleton, instance-variables

Everything I know about programming says that instance methods can call class methods, but class methods **cannot** call instance methods.

This post agrees... 
[Call instance method from class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121880/call-instance-method-from-class-method)

Yet miraculously the class method `sharedInstance` manages to call instance method `init`.  What am I missing ??

```
static iRpDatabase *sharedDatabase;

@implementation iRpDatabase
{ 
}

    +(iRpDatabase*)sharedInstance
    {
        if(sharedDatabase == nil)
        {
            sharedDatabase = [[self alloc] init];
        }
        return sharedDatabase;
    }

    // this is an instance method, called from class method above.
    -(id)init
    {
        if (self = [super init]) {
            someInstanceVariable = XYZ;
            [self someInstanceMethod];
        }
        return self;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that a class method can't call instance methods means that the class method can't call instance methods on `self` since `self` represents the class, not an instance of the class.

In the `sharedInstance` method you are calling an instance method but it is being called on a specific instance of the class. That's fine.

Think of this example:

```
+ (void)someClassMethodOfiRpDatabase {
    NSString *str = @"Hello";
    NSInteger len = [str length]; // look - I called an instance method
}
```

This example in no different than your `sharedInstance` method question. It's fine to call instance methods on a specific instance of an object, even if you happen to be in some class method.

Comment: If you look at your example (which we can see on any subclass of NSObject) you'll see that you are not calling init on self but on the result of [self alloc]   -which is an instance. Best

Comment: @Jef You should post your comment to the question, not this answer.