# Difference between + and - methods in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

What is the difference between methods that are declared with - and methods that are declared with +

e.g

```
- (void)methodname

+ (void)methodname
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Methods prefixed with `-` are instance methods. This means they can only be invoked on an instance of a class, eg:

```
[myStringInstance length];
```

Methods prefixed with `+` are class methods. This means they can be called on Classes, without needing an instance, eg:

```
[NSString stringWithString:@"Hello World"];
```

Comment: Just curious: why this choice of notation? +/- feels a bit hackish to me (probably because it reminds me of how perl uses '@', '#', '$' to mean *something*)

Comment: I can't comment on the choice of notation, because I simply don't know... Sorry. Maybe someone else will know?

Comment: UML uses +/- sure.  Also UML uses +/- to annotate methods.  However other than that UML's use and Obj-C use are completely different.

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil I think uml uses +/- signs to for public/private attribute or functions. (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/images/notation_class.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

`+(void)methodname` is a class variable and `-(void)methodname` is object variable.

Lets say you make a utility class that has a method to reverse string. The class you call MYUtility.

If you use +, like

```
+ (NSString *)reverse:(NSString *)stringToReverse
```

You could use it directly like

```
NSString *reversed = [MYUtility stringToReverse:@"I Love objective C"];
```

if you used a -, like

```
- (NSString *)reverse:(NSString *)stringToReverse
```

You have to use :

```
MYUtility *myUtil = [[MYUtility alloc] init];
NSString *reversed = [myUtil stringToReverse:@"There are many ways to do the same thing"];
```

With the class based  function, you just call directly, but you don't have access to any local variables besides #defines that you can do because the class isn't instantiated.

But with the - (NSString you must instantiate the class before use, and you have access to all local variables.

This isn't a pick one thing and stay with it, many classes have both, just look at the header file for NSString, it is littered with + functions and - functions.

Answer (score 2):

minus are instance methods (only accessible via an instantiated object)

plus are class methods (like in Java Math.abs(), you can use it without an instantited object)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html):

> Instance methods begin with - and class level methods begin with +

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The first is an instance method and the second is a class method. You should read Apple's Objective-C documentation to learn about the difference.