# Calling objective C from Swift error = Class does not have a member called

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to call an Objective-C class from Swift. So I enabled the bridging header option

Created the following files:

**MyTest.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyTest : NSObject
+(void)sayHello;
@end
```

**MyTest.m**

```
@implementation MyTest

+(void)sayHello {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}

@end
```

at `MyProject-Bridging-Header.h`added:

```
#import "MyTest.h"
```

Then when in a Swift file I call:

```
let test = MyTest()
test.sayHello()
```

The compiler complains in the second line:

```
MyTest does not have a member named 'sayHello'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I have no experience with Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a class method, not an instance method.

Try instead:

```
MyTest.sayHello()
```

Or change the objective-c function to:

```
-(void)sayHello
```

Note the `-` instead of the `+`.  See this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238584/difference-between-and-methods-in-objective-c) for further reading.