# How to call static methods of parent class in Objective - C.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, superclass

**Question:**
How to call **superclass** ***static*** ***method*** ?

I mean directly by using:

`[SuperClassName method]`

OR

There is any other way existed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691383/how-can-i-make-a-static-method-in-objective-ci may help you.

Comment: Exactly as you posted... `[SuperClassName method]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wants to call drive class methods from base class then, declare class method in your drive class like this: using (+) sign before method name.

```
+(void)myClassMethod;
```

Call this method from base class like this:

```
[YourDriveClassName myClassMethod];
```

Or you wants to call drive class instance methods from base class, declare instance method in your drive class using (-)sign before method name.

```
-(void)sayHelloToSomeOne:(NSString *)greeting;
```

Call this method from base class.

```
[super sayHelloToSomeOne:@"Hello Worlds!"];
```

Answer (score 4):

**In Objective-C, there are two type of Methods:**

**1) Class Method**

e.g:

`+ (void)aClassMethod;`

You can call this method by his class name like : `[MyClass aClassMethod]`

**2) Instance Method**

e.g:

`- (void)anInstanceMethod;`

You can call this method by his class's instance name like :

`MyClass *object = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[object anInstanceMethod];`

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If the call is from a static method. That is

```
+ (void)someMethod{
  [self method];
}
```

if call is from an instance method it is really required to call it like

```
- (void)someMethod{
  [SuperClassName method];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will declare a class level method in iOS to use "+" before the method declaration.

declared in your class.h file

```
+ (void)yourStaticMethod;
```

// call is from anywhere

```
[yourClassName myStaticMethod];
```