# Difference Class and Instance Methods

Tags: objective-c, methods, conventions

Whats the difference between class methods and Instance methods. Why do we need them separately?
Can somebody please explain?

Class and Instance Methods

• Instances respond to instance methods

```
 - (id)init;
 - (float)height;
 - (void)walk;
```

• Classes respond to class methods

```
 + (id)alloc;
 + (id)person;
 + (Person *)sharedPerson;
```

Taimur

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Class vs Instance Methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An instance method is only available on an instance of the class, while a class method does not need an instance but is available on the class.

Class Methods are denoted by a `+` while instance methods are denoted by a `-` before their return type.

Let's take `NSObject` for example. `NSObject` has a class method named `+ (id)alloc`. The alloc method is used to allocate an instance of the class. Obviously alloc must be  a class method because if it was an instance method, where would you get the "root" instance from?

On the other hand    `- (id)init` is an instance method because it initializes the state of an instance.

Comment: Good answer, to clarify with an example from the code included in the question. If you asked the class what height it was [Person height] it doesnt have an answer because a person can be any height. But if you ask an instance say [michael height] it can respond  because I could have set a height for that specific instance (person).

Answer (score 5):

An example:

`Human` -> `Class`
`You` -> `Instance`

`Human` could `extinguish`, `you` cannot.
`You` could `drink a Coke`, `Human` cannot.

`Instance` method is only applied to individuals,

While `Class` method is applied to the whole group with the same identifiable features.

It's the difference between one and many, individual and the whole society.

`[SomeClass alloc]` means a new instance of the class is born
just like You are given birth,

`init` applies to an `Instance`, like your parents give you a name, feed you and send you to school, so you have skills to live in this society.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Static variables
2. Represent by '+' symbol
3. Can be called directly with class without creating instance of a class
4. Self in class method represent class itself however self in instance method represents that particular instance of a class.