# Where to Use Class Method ,Instance Method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, class-method, instance-methods

"Instance" mean  in Objective-C?
Kindly tell me where to use Class Method And where to use Instance Method,also tell me where we use (Instacetype) method?
why/where we use multi Parameters?

Comment: Simply how did you create the object ?
NSObject  *obj = [[NSObject alloc]init];
In this alloc is the class method and init is the instance method ...

Comment: Directly we are calling through the class name is class method and some restriction are there pls refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-methods class methods-
 it is just like a static method

Comment: This is too broad for stackoverflow, which is about answering programming questions, not to teach computer science.  Buy a book or join a class.

Comment: Hope this helps you: [Purpose of Instance Methods vs. Class Methods in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174526/purpose-of-instance-methods-vs-class-methods-in-objective-c) ,

Answer (score 1):

A class method is a method whose self parameter is a reference to the class's class object.

An instance method is a method whose self parameter is a reference to a specific instance of the class.

Those are the technical differences.

A more practical answer is that an instance method operates on a single instance of the class, while a class method operates at a more global, non-specific level.  A class method can act as a factory method, such as `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat:` method.  It can also be used to configure behavior that will affect all instances of the class.  It can also be used to operate on a collection of instances of the class, such as sorting or filtering.

`instancetype` is a keyword that can be used as a placeholder for the current class's type.  It says to the compiler: pretend that I wrote <my class name> here, so if you see the result of this method assigned somewhere, you know what type it's supposed to be.