# Objective C - Call Method defined from a Macro

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native, native-module, react-native-native-module

I'm trying to call a Method from Objective-C that has been defined using a Macro which wraps a Swift function. I'm getting the compilation error `No visible @interface for 'NearbyMessages' declares the selector '__rct_export__disconnect'` in Xcode when I try to call my Method though.

My Swift function looks like this:

```swift
// SomeInterface.swift

@objc
func disconnect() -> Void {
    // (disconnect logic here)
}
```

The Objective-C code looks like this:

```c
// SomeInterface.m
@interface RCT_EXTERN_REMAP_MODULE(SomeInterfaceNameJS, SomeInterfaceNamePrivate, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(disconnect);
-(void) invalidate {
    [self __rct_export__disconnect];   // No visible @interface for 'NearbyMessages' declares the selector '__rct_export__disconnect'
    NSLog(@"GNM_BLE: invalidate!");
}

@end
```

The macro `RCT_EXTERN_METHOD` (from React's `RCTBridgeModule.h`) is defined as:

```c
#define RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(method) \
  _RCT_EXTERN_REMAP_METHOD(, method, NO)

#define _RCT_EXTERN_REMAP_METHOD(js_name, method, is_blocking_synchronous_method) \
  + (const RCTMethodInfo *)RCT_CONCAT(__rct_export__, RCT_CONCAT(js_name, RCT_CONCAT(__LINE__, __COUNTER__))) { \
    static RCTMethodInfo config = {#js_name, #method, is_blocking_synchronous_method}; \
    return &config; \
  }
```

By reading this, upon compilation the Method should be called `__rct_export__disconnect`, right?

So why is it not possible to use `[self __rct_export__disconnect]` - How else can I call this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: To answer the question, call `[self.class __rct_export__disconnect];`. But it is better (and an only future-proof way in case the `__rct_export__` prefix changes in the next versions of React Native) is to call the `disconnect()` function directly.

---

Objective-C allows having two main types of methods.

First type is the *instance method*, which operates on an instance of the Objective-C class. In the body of this method, `self` is a pointer to the instance of the object on the heap, hence the name. Through the `self` pointer you can access other instance methods, instance variables etc. It is declared/defined with a minus (-) sign in the beginning.

Second type is the *class method*, which operates on *class objects* (a specific Obj-C construct). It is most commonly used when you'd use a static function in other languages (with some caveats and quirks related to inheritance of course). In the body of this method, `self` is a pointer to the *class object*. Through it you can call other class methods, but you **don't have access** to any concrete instances of the object.

The difference is explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11174572/737347).

---

In your case, this macro defines a class method:

```
#define _RCT_EXTERN_REMAP_METHOD(js_name, method, is_blocking_synchronous_method) \
  + (const RCTMethodInfo *)RCT_CONCAT(__rct_export__, RCT_CONCAT(js_name, RCT_CONCAT(__LINE__, __COUNTER__))) { \
    static RCTMethodInfo config = {#js_name, #method, is_blocking_synchronous_method}; \
    return &config; \
  }
```

And this method is an instance method:

```
- (void)invalidate {
    [self __rct_export__disconnect];   // No visible @interface for 'NearbyMessages' declares the selector '__rct_export__disconnect'
    NSLog(@"GNM_BLE: invalidate!");
}
```

When you call `[self __rct_export__disconnect];]` from the *instance method*, the `self` points to the *instance* of your class. The `__rct_export__disconnect` is defined as a class method (see macro), and thus it is not defined on the instances of the object.

Comment: That's a very good answer, marking this as accepted - however if anyone stumbles upon the same issue, I just found out it's also possible to just create the `invalidate` func in Swift and expose it to Objective-C (`@objc`).

Comment: @mrousavy, do you perhaps have an example for exposing the swift function to Objective-C?  Because this is literally what we're trying to do in this question, and a couple lines of code does wonders!  THanks.