# instance method of class for iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to create some header file for future use but i have 1 problem

i have defined a method in lets say Rimage class  called check1
now  i want to call that from maiviewcont

so i did this
in mainVC.h
i defined a instance of Rimage class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class Rimage;
@interface Rahul_imageplaceCordinatesViewController : UIViewController {

    Rimage *aRimage;
}
@property (nonatomic,copy) Rimage *aRimage;
@end
```

and in .m

```
[self.aRimage check1];
aRimage = [Rimage check1];
```

but both are not working

i went for both +(void)check1 and -(void)check1 in Rimage class

Comment: do you have the @synthesize in the .m file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two examples you give do very different things:

```
[self.aRimage check1];
```

invokes an `check1` instance method on `aRimage`.

```
aRimage = [Rimage check1];
```

calls the `check1` class method on the `Rimage` class, and assigns the result to `aRimage`.

In both cases, you will need to `#import "Rimage.h` in your .m file, else you'll get warnings like "aRimage may not respond to 'check1'".

---

EDIT

Your ".h" file is declaring a property named "aRimage", but that value will be nil until you assign something to it, by doing something like:

```
self.aRimage = [[[Rimage alloc] init] autorelease];
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods) for a good explanation of the difference between class methods and instance methods.

ps. and don't forget to do a `[aRimage release]` in your dealloc method

Comment: but why i am cant see any output  i already initialize an instance in .h of VC do i need to alloc them in .m

Comment: by instance method you mean -(void)check1 and by class method you mean +(void)check1  thats it???