# Trying to change variables in a singleton using a method

Tags: ios5, singleton

I am trying to use a singleton to store variables that will be used across multiple view controllers. I need to be able to get the variables and also set them. How do I call a method in a singleton to change the variables stored in the singleton.

```
 total+=1079;
[var setTotal:total];
```

where var is a

```
static Singleton *var = nil;
```

I need to update the total and send to the setTotal method inside the singleton. But when I do this the setTotal method never gets accessed. The get methods work but the setTotal method does not. Please let me know what should. Below is some of my source code

```
   //
//  Singleton.m
//  Rolo
//
//  Created by  on 6/28/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Johnny Cox. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Singleton.h"

@implementation Singleton
@synthesize total,tax,final;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (Singleton *)sharedManager
{
    static Singleton *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[Singleton alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

+(void) setTotal:(double) tot
{
    Singleton *shared = [Singleton sharedManager];
    shared.total = tot;
    NSLog(@"hello");
}
+(double) getTotal
{
    Singleton *shared = [Singleton sharedManager];
    NSLog(@"%f",shared.total);
    return shared.total;
}
+(double) getTax
{
    Singleton *shared = [Singleton sharedManager];
    NSLog(@"%f",shared.tax);
    return shared.tax;
}
@end


//
//  Singleton.h
//  Rolo
//
//  Created by  on 6/28/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Johnny Cox. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Singleton : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) double total;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double tax;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double final;

+ (id)sharedManager;
+(double) getTotal;
+(void) setTotal;
+(double) getTax;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have attempted to implement your getters and setter as *class methods* instead of *instance methods*. Attributes are properties of your singleton, not of its class. For more on instance methods vs class methods in objective-c see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375443/difference-between-class-methods-and-instance-methods)

You'll have better luck with something more like:

```
-(double) getTotal;
-(void) setTotal:(double) total;
-(double) getTax;
```