# Will this work?

Tags: objective-c

```
UILabel *testLbl = [[self alloc] init];
```

This is where the confusion started:

It’s usually better to use a variable other than self to refer to an instance inside a class
method:

```
+ (id)rectangleOfColor:(NSColor *)color {
id newInstance = [[Rectangle alloc] init]; // GOOD [newInstance setColor:color]; return [newInstance autorelease];
}
```

In fact, rather than sending the alloc message to the class in a class method, it’s often better to send alloc to self. This way, if the class is subclassed, and the rectangleOfColor: message is received by a subclass, the instance returned will be the same type as the subclass (for example, the array method of NSArray is inherited by NSMutableArray).

```
+ (id)rectangleOfColor:(NSColor *)color {
id newInstance = [[self alloc] init]; // EXCELLENT [newInstance setColor:color]; return [newInstance autorelease];
}
```

Comment: means is there any difference between the two:

UILabel *testLbl = [[self alloc] init];
UILabel *testLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];

Comment: Are you running this in a UILabel instance method? then you could use `[[[self class] alloc] init]`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't work. In your first line, you are sending the `alloc` message to an *instance of a class*. In the examples you copied out of Apple's documentation, they are sending `alloc` messages to the *Class* `Rectangle`. The difference is that your line is (apparently) inside an instance method, Apple's examples are inside class methods. [There is a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods).

Like @Denis mentioned, you can do what you're trying to do by saying `[[[self class] alloc] init]`, but in practice, don't do this. You'll almost never need the flexibility this offers and it will only muddy the intent of the new object.

Answer (score 2):

No, It'll cause a "UILable undeclared (first use in this function)" error.