# please tell me what is exception in this code

Tags: iphone

```
NSString *qry=@"UPDATE TABLE USERBASIC SET F_NAME='%@',M_NAME='%@',L_NAME='%@' WHERE REGISTRATIONID='%@'";
NSString *updtQuery=[[NSString alloc] stringWithFormat:qry,fname.text,mname.text,lname.text,userInformationId];
NSLog(@"try UPDATE %@:",updtQuery);
```

this gives invalid argument exception.. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *updtQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:qry,fname.text,mname.text,lname.text,userInformationId];
```

or

```
NSString *updtQuery=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:qry,fname.text,mname.text,lname.text,userInformationId];
```

Comment: Go ahead and accept this one, he beat me by 20 seconds. Fair is fair. :)

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
[[NSString alloc] stringWithFormat...]
```

`stringWithFormat` is a class method; you use it as `[NSString stringWithFormat: ...]`

See also:

- [Learning Objective-C: A Primer: Methods and Messaging](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594-CH1-SW11) (Apple)
- [What is the difference between class and instance methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods) (Previous Stack Overflow question)