# Objective-C - Access method from other controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, controller

i have a little question about getting access to a method in another controller, nu i am trying this. 
So for example i have the controller A and B. In the controller A i have programmed a method, now i want to get access this through controller B.

What i have done in class A in the header file:

```
+(void)goBack;
```

and in the implementation file:

```
+(void)goBack {
NSLog(@"go back");
}
```

in the controller B i do this to get access to the method in controller A:

```
+(void)goPreviousArticle:(id)sender {
ViewProductInformation_ViewController *theInstance = [[ViewProductInformation_ViewController alloc] init];
[theInstance goBack];
}
```

However when i execute the program, then it does not work, the program just shuts down, when i do command click on the function goBack in controller B i get referred to the method in controller A.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be?

thanks in advance,

snowy

Comment: Xcode is just the IDE - the language is Objective-C. (As such, I've re-tagged your question.)

Comment: Why you use static(+) functions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy ... you just mixed the class and instance-method declaration: The "+" sign indicates that the method is a class method. In your case it should be a "-" so

```
-(void)goBack; // a instance method declaration!
```

Hope this helps.

Class vs instance method declaration ... see also [What is the difference between class and instance methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)

Comment: this surely helps ! i am glad after many hours of searching that you could give me a solution. also thank you for the explanation, it has cleared out a lot for me !

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring goBack as a CLASS method (with the preceding "+").  Change the + to a -.

Answer (score 0):

Since goBack is a static method of Class A, you don't need an instance of A to call it's method, you can just call it like so:

[ClassA goBack];

Comment: I tried this, but does not worked out for me, the solution above works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don'y need to declare static functions you can writ like this:

```
-(void)goBack {
NSLog(@"go back");
}
```

In the class A and same in the class B:

```
-(void)goPreviousArticle:(id)sender {
ViewProductInformation_ViewController *theInstance = [[ViewProductInformation_ViewController alloc] init];
[theInstance goBack];
}
```

Then use them. I think in that case application will not crashed.