# What's wrong with this message?

Tags: objective-c

Here is the message:

```
[SQLiteDB addRecordToDatabase:(ZBarSymbol *)symbol];  //  add this record to the d/b
```

Here is the definition of the message in the .h file:

```
- (void)addRecordToDatabase:(ZBarSymbol *)symbol ;
```

Here is the implementation of the message:

```
//---------------------    addRecordToDatabase    ----------------------|
- (void)addRecordToDatabase: (ZBarSymbol *)symbol  {
```

I get the following error during execution:

```
2011-05-04 07:07:32.518 PointPeek[208:707] +[SQLiteDB addRecordToDatabase:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x276b8
2011-05-04 07:07:32.574 PointPeek[208:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SQLiteDB addRecordToDatabase:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x276b8'
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is declared as instance method and used as class method. Class methods are declared with a "+" sign.

```
+ (void)addRecordToDatabase:(ZBarSymbol *)symbol;
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods) discusses instance vs class methods.