# Why is my method not found?

Tags: objective-c

In my h file I have

```
+(CCRenderTexture*) createStroke: (CCLabelTTF*) label
                            size:(float)size   
                           color:(ccColor3B)cor;
```

In my m file I implemented this method and use it like

```
CCRenderTexture* stroke = [self createStroke:pause  size:3  color:ccBLACK];
```

But it gives me a warning "method not found". Why?

Comment: where are you calling that method? In another class method or in an instance method?

Comment: in my init method where I initialize my instance

Comment: Too lazy to actually explain it, so just as a comment: Remove the + and insert a - instead. Or: Don't use self but instead CCRenderTexture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the `+createStroke` is a class method, you can't call it on `self`. You should instead send that message to the `CCRenderTexture` class.

So, in your case, if `self` is of the `CCRenderTexture` type, you could just replace it with `self.class`. (So that when you will subclass, the overridden method will be called by the superclass)
If it is not, write something like:

```
CCRenderTexture* stroke = [CCRenderTexture createStroke:pause size:3 color:ccBLACK];
```

Answer (score 2):

plus means it is a class method, so you need to use the Class Name instead of an instance of that class: [ClassName createStroke:pause  size:3  color:ccBLACK] 
You probably want to have an instance method, so put a minus instead of plus in your declaration.

Here is some more info on this topic: [What is the difference between class and instance methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)