# how to call a method from another class method which consists of IBAction method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Actually i am testing a sample application in iPhone...where in user interface if i press a button "hello" message should display on text field...such a way that when button pressed it should call a method present in another class i.e, from class2 and display a message on UI
so Please help me.... the following code is given below
i have two classes say class1 and class2...
in class1 i am calling

**class1.h**

```
@interface class1 : UIViewController {

      IBOutlet UILabel *statusText;    


}

@property (nonatomic,retain)UILabel *statusText;

- (void)buttonpressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

**class1.m**

```
@implemenation class1

-(IBAction)sayhello:(id)sender

{
class1ViewController *class = [[class1ViewController alloc]init];

    [class hello];
}
```

**class2.h**

```
@interface class2 : UIViewController {

    UILabel *statusText;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)UILabel *statusText;


-(void)sayhello:(id)sender;


@end
```

**class2.m**

```
@implementation class2

-(void)sayhello:(id)sender;
{

    NSString *newtext = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"hello"];

    statusText.text = newtext;

    [newtext release];
 }
```

Please suggest what changes I should make in the code so that when I press a button it should display the message "HELLO" by calling a method in another class.... I have taken two classes.. I have used IBAction methods...
I want to call a method using another class.

thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: so let me get this straight you want to call the method present in the class 2 inside the class 1 right is that what you wana do

Comment: A few bits of advice. 1) Class names should always start with a capital letter. `Class1` `Class2`. 2) `UIViewController` classes should only be used for full-screen display. If you have a text field and a button on the screen simultaneously, they should usually be accessed via the same view controller. 3) Use the `@"..."` construct to create strings. `statusText.text = @"hello";`. It's a lot cleaner.

Comment: References for [naming conventions](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php), [view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html), [creating strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html)

Comment: plz make your self clear whether you want to know how to show something in view or you want to know how to call a method in another class, or probably, both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi are you aware of writing this

```
class1ViewController *class = [[class1ViewController alloc]init];
```

I think it should be:-

```
-(IBAction)sayhello:(id)sender

{
class2 *class = [[class2 alloc]init];
   NSString *string= [class sayhello];
    [class release];
label.text=string;
}
```

dont forget to import class2 in class1

in class2
 simply write:-

```
-(NSString)sayhello
{
    return @"hello";

 }
```

Comment: @Abhilash I am curious to know does the answer help you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `[class hello]`, use `[class sayhello:nil]`.

A few notes: the names of classes should begin with a capital letter, e.g. *Class1* and *Class2*. Also, `buttonpressed:` passes a `sender`, you are however not using it. It also works when you remove the `:(id)sender`. And when you set the `text` of `statusText`, you create a new string first. This does the same: `statusText.text = @"hello"`;

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
class2 * _class2Object = [[class2 alloc]init];
[_class2Object sayHello];
```

and dont forget to import class2 in class1 else app may crash, since you want to call the method of class2 in class1 so import the class2.h header in class1 and add the above code.

Answer (score 0):

theoretically, since you are calling a object method(I suppose you know what is the difference between a object method and a class method), so you should alloc and initiate a object of the class which contains the method you want to call(here class2).

I suggest that you display some string made by class2 in class1's view:

so in class1:

```
-(IBAction)sayHello
{
class2* c2 = [[class2 alloc] init];
statusText.text = [c2 sayhello];
[c2 release];
}
```

in class2:

```
-(NSString*)sayhello
{
return @"a string";
}
```

Comment: tel me difference between object method and class method...?

Comment: @Abhilash to call a object method, you must have a instance of a class, like [c2 sayhello]; above. To call a class method, you don't have to have a instance of a class, if class2 has a class method named singHello, you can call like this: [class2 singHello];

Comment: @Abhilash check this question's answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods