# Explanation of Class Methods and Instance Method

Tags: objective-c, class-method, instance-methods

Until now, I would like to know the difference between these 2. I always been using instance methods but have no idea the meaning behind it. Can anyone explain in the simplest way? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Class vs Instance Methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)

Comment: thanks for the link. the one I saw was the java. Although explanation could be the same. I was looking for the obj c one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class methods are called on the classes themselves, like this:

```
[NSDate date];
// declared as: + (NSDate *)date;
```

Instance methods are called on actual objects:

```
NSDate *date = ...;
[date timeIntervalSinceNow];
// declared as: - (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceNow;
```

Read the [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW1) guide for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but even if I just read the link j0k sent. I am still feeling confused.

Comment: What are you confused about? Did you read the link I put in my answer? Class/instance methods are common to many object-oriented languages, so it would be good to get a grasp on OOP in general.

Comment: Yea, I read your link. But still I do not understand still. Can I say that Class methods can only call methods within its own class? Thats what I am seeing in your code.

Comment: oh man, now i feel more confused :( 
i guess it would be better if i find some obj c tutorials on class and instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well class methods can be used without making an instance of a class.
Since you don't have an instance of this class you can't use any class instance variables.

ex:

```
@implementation MyStringHelper


@synthesize lastChecked;

+ (BOOL) checkIfEmptyString:(NSString *)checkString {
  return ([checkString length] == 0);
}
@end
```

Thus you can call this like:

```
if ( [MyStringHelper checkIfEmptyString:@"NotEmprty"] ) {
// do something
}
```

But you can't use the properties `latChecked` because this will need an instance of the `MyStringHelper` class.