# Objective-C singleton only responds to class methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, singleton

I have a singleton class that is instantiated as follows:

```
#import "FavoritesManager.h"

static FavoritesManager *sharedFavoritesManager = nil;

@implementation FavoritesManager

+ (id)sharedManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedFavoritesManager == nil) {
            sharedFavoritesManager = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

This returns an object, but for some reason it will only respond to class methods. If I call a instance method I get

```
+[FavoritesManager testMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x59198
```

For what it's worth, this is what testMethod looks like:

```
- (void)testMethod {
    NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

and I'm absolutely positive it's declared in the interface. I've used this exact code in other classes and it works like a charm, so I don't really understand what the problem is here. One thing that is suspicious is the plus sign in `+[FavoritesManager testMethod]`, but I can't explain it. Any ideas?

EDIT: I was confusing public/private and class/method terminology. Thanks to everyone who pointed that out.

Comment: You're confusing public methods with Class methods and private methods with instance methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that you're sending the message `testMethod` to the class, rather than an instance.

The reason for this is that your `sharedManager` method is incorrect. You are currently returning `self`, which, in this class method, is the class itself. This means that when you write `[[FavoritesManager sharedManger] testMethod]` you end up sending `testMethod` to the class. Since `testMethod` isn't a class method, you get an error.

You should have `return sharedFavoritesManager;` at the end of `sharedManager`, not `return self;`. The latter is correct only in instance method initializers.

Also, as dbrajkovic commented, you seem to be confused about public/private and class/instance methods. Strictly, ObjC has no private methods. You can hide the declaration, which will cause a compiler warning, but the message will still be sent and the method will be called. The `+` and `-` distinguish class methods from instance methods; the distinction is which kind of object you send a message to. Info here: [What is the difference between class and instance methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to call testMethod from another class method then you need:

```
+ (void)testMethod {
    NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

The reason is that if you call a class method then there's no instance, so nothing on which to call instance methods. But probably you want to call:

```
[[FavoritesManager sharedManager] testMethod];
```

Which means 'get the shared instance, then call `testMethod` on it'. Thinking as I type, you might also like to add:

```
+ (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    id sharedManager = [self sharedManager];

    if ([sharedManager respondsToSelector:
            [anInvocation selector]])
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:sharedManager];
    else
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
}
```

Which is the Objective-C means for message forwarding. So if the metaclass `FavoritesManager` receives a message it can't respond to, it lets its shared manager instance have a go. That means that:

```
[FavoritesManager testMethod];
```

Becomes functionally equivalent to (though a little slower than):

```
[[FavoritesManager sharedManager] testMethod];
```

Providing that you haven't implemented a class method in addition to an instance method. You can learn more about message forwarding in [Apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH105-SW1).

Answer (score 2):

The error is right you must be calling `[FavoritesManager testMethod]` which means you're trying to call a class method. I believe you want `[[FavoritesManager sharedManager] testMethod];`

Answer (score 1):

+ at the start of a method declaration means that it's a class method, - means that it's an instance method. Do this:

```
+(void)testMethod {
    NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

If you want to invoke testMethod on your sharedManager, then keep the testMethod declaration as you have it and instead change your invocation to

```
[[FavoritesManager sharedFavoritesManager] testMethod];
```

Either will work, and choosing between the two is a matter of app design.

Answer (score 1):

Instead try

```
[[FavoritesManager sharedFavoritesManager] testMethod];
```

Answer (score 0):

there are no priavte methods in obj-c.
But anyway on a singleton you are always calling from the outside of the class, so only declare "public methods". for detailed help post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Call your singleton instance:

[[ FavoritesManager sharedManager] testMethod];