# Followup on: Difference between class methods and instance methods?

Tags: objective-c, class, methods

This is a followup question to (user) micmoo's response on [What is the difference between class and instance methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods) .

If I change the variable: numberOfPeople from static to a local variable in the class, I get numberOfPeople as 0. I have also added a line to show the numberOfPeople after the variable has been incremented each time. Just to avoid any confusion, my code is as follows:

```
// Diffrentiating between class method and instance method

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


// static int numberOfPeople = 0;

@interface MNPerson : NSObject {
    int age;  //instance variable
    int numberOfPeople;
}

+ (int)population; //class method. Returns how many people have been made.
- (id)init; //instance. Constructs object, increments numberOfPeople by one.
- (int)age; //instance. returns the person age
@end

@implementation MNPerson

int numberOfPeople = 0; 
- (id)init{

    if (self = [super init]){
        numberOfPeople++;
        NSLog(@"Number of people = %i", numberOfPeople);
        age = 0;
    }    
    return self;
}

+ (int)population{ 
    return numberOfPeople;
}

- (int)age{
    return age;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {


    MNPerson *micmoo = [[MNPerson alloc] init];
    MNPerson *jon = [[MNPerson alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Age: %d",[micmoo age]);
    NSLog(@"Number Of people: %d",[MNPerson population]);
}

}
```

Output:

In init block. Number of people = 1 In init block. Number of people = 1 Age: 0 Number Of people: 0

Case 2: If you change the numberOfPeople in the implementation to 5 (say). The output still does not make sense.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You're not changing the type, you're creating a new variable.

Answer (score 2):

You are hiding the globally declared `numberOfPeople` with the instance level `numberOfPeople`.  Change one of their names to something else to avoid this problem