# Class Methods and Instance methods

Tags: objective-c

Class methods are static methods? Is this argument true? So if we declare NSString since alloc is a class methods

NSString *hello = [[NSString alloc] init];
class method

[hello isEqualtoString: @"Hello"];
instance method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *think* of a class method as being similar to a `static` method in C++, as in

```
[NSString alloc]  <=>  /* hypothetical */ NSString::alloc()
```

But behind the scenes, there are major differences.  For example, in a C++ `static` method you cannot use `this`; in an Objective-C class method, `self` is perfectly valid and refers to the class object.

Answer (score 2):

In **Object Oriented Programming** a *class method* is a method/function that is applied to/called by a class and not a particular instance of it, ie an object of that class. An *instance method* is a method called directly on an object.

In some languages each class is represented by a Class object and so a class method is an instance method of that object. This is useful to apply reflection and introspection.

In objective-c class methods are defined by using the symbol `+` preceding its declaration, whereas instance ones use the `-` before them. Here is an example:

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject

    + (void)join:(Rectangle *)firstRect withAnother:(Rectangle *)secondRect;
    - (void)area;

@end
```

Class methods are frequently used when you do not need to refer to a particular object, or you have to change all of them or you just need a place for a function that is not related to instance objects.

You said **`static`** in your question. You are probably referring to languages like Java which have the keyword static come before the declaration of a class method. In objective-c the keyword static has the same meaning of it [used in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program).

As a reference you can have a look at [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods?rq=1) or at [this paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Class_methods).