# UIImage Class im having difficulty

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uiimageview, uiimage

Can anyone give me an example of code or project that uses because I want to animate a full screen image(iPhone) with 200+ of images without crashing the device.

`+ (UIImage *)animatedImageNamed:(NSString *)name duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`

Also on how to call it for example like `[self (method)]` and regarding on how to stop the animation on it. Because when I read it in the apple documentation, I am having a hard time because I don't see a sample code regarding to that syntax. By the way, I am a trainee at iOS development.

Answer (score 1):

In the method signature you can see the `+` sign showing that is not an instance but a class method (see the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)). In order to call it you use

```
UIImage * myAnimatedImage = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"Imagename.png" duration:12.0f];
myImageView.image = myAnimatedImage; // the same as [myImageView setImage:myAnimatedImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

Two hundred full screen images take a lot of memory.  You should convert your images to a [video file](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html) instead and use an `AVPlayerLayer` to play it.  You will need to read [the Playback section of the *AV Foundation Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW1).

Comment: Or he could use Cocos2D to have control over the images