# Why we put '+' or '-' sign in front of method name in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C: Class vs Instance Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)

Why we put '+'  or '-' sign in front of method name in iOS. Please help me on sign logic and what's the difference in that ?

Comment: yes, but for confirmation and more explanation, i thought to ask.

Comment: No problem, its good to ask for more specification.

Comment: "+" Indicates that it is a class method and it will be directly accessible via class name. 
"-" Indicates, it is a instance method and can be accessible by class instance.

Answer (score 7):

It has nothing to do with signs;

`+` means the method is a class method, that is, it operates on (or, rather, its scope is) the class itself, not instances. The corresponding thing in many other languages is `static`.

`-` means the method is an instance method, that is, it operates on instances of the class.

Comment: thanks to all friends :)

Answer (score 3):

```
`@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
}

+(id) someMethod;  // declaration of class method

-(id) someMethod;  // declaration of instance method

@end`
```

Instance methods apply on instances of classes, so they need an object to be applied on and  can access their caller's members.

On the other hand class methods apply on the whole class, they don't rely on any object.

check this link for proper knowledge [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_Objective-C_Class_Methods)

Answer (score 2):

A minus `-` sign denotes an instance [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Static_methods). A plus `+` sign is a [class method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Class_methods).

Answer (score 2):

The leading + sign denotes a class method, the - sign means an instance method.

Side note: this should not be asked here - read that tutorial more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The `-` prefix denotes an instance method, and the `+` prefix denotes a class (or static) method.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods) (and many other) SO posts for more information.