# "Instance variable 'xxx' accessed in class method....why?

Tags: iphone, xcode, methods, instance, instance-variables

So please forgive me as I am very new to stackoverflow and to ios programming in general.

I am attempting to change the text of a button i have, replacing current text with a date string (`dateStringForInput`) I am passing in from another class.  The button is called `myTodayButton` and is declared in my `.h` file for my class `inputMilesViewController`...
   `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myTodayButton`;

Below is the code from my .m.

```
+(void) changeButtonText:(NSString*) dateStringForInput{

     NSLog(@"we got to changebuttontext");
     [_myTodayButton setTitle:dateStringForInput forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I am getting the following error "Instance variable "`_myTodayButton`" accessed in class method.

I understand that this is written in a class method rather than an instance method but i cant figure out how to get this change to happen.  the button which prompts this call to `changeButtonText`  is in the other class which is creating `dateStringForInput`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Try like this...

**For (+) instance.**

`+ (void) changeButtonText`: Only have access to the self object.

--**Step 1:** Remove follwing line from **header** file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myTodayButton;
```

--**Step 2:**

- Add `UIButton *myTodayButton` in your class file globally..
- That means declare before `@implementation`

Eg: In **.m File**

```
#import "Controller.h"
UIButton *myTodayButton // Add like this before @implementation

@implementation Controller
```

---

**For (-) instance**

`- (void) changeButtonText`: Only have access to the instance methods

Answer (score 0):

change method to an instance method instead of a class method ("-" instead of  "+") create an instance of the class and then simply call it like so:

```
MyClass *classInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[classInstance changeButtonText:@"stringText"];
```

Also its recommended to have weak properties for IBOutlets.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

[EDIT]

Regarding your second issue with segues. Firstly do you really need a different view controller for simply displaying a UIDatePicker? I normally display them in the same UIViewController using an actionSheet, its a little work to get just right but solves this problem. I can post the code if you like?

Anyway if you want to keep your current setup I would do the following:

1. In the ViewController that contains the button create a new public NSString property in the .h file.

   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dateString;
2. In the View Controller that contains the date picker, after the user has selected the date override the perpareForSegue method. In here get the destination view controller (which is the one with the button and new string property created in point one above) and set the dateString.

   ```
   - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

   MyViewController *todayViewController = (MyViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
   [todayViewController setDateString:@"valueYouRequire"];
   ```

   }
3. In the ViewController with the button set the button's title in the viewDidLoad to be the dateString.

   - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
     [super viewDidLoad];

   if (self.dateString) [self.myTodayButton setTitle:self.dateString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }

[EDIT]

If you want to go down the actionSheet route then add this method to the ViewController with the button and play around with the frame sizes to fit your needs. The method below creates a date picker, adds it to an actionSheet and displays the actionSheet.

```
- (IBAction) datePressed:(id)sender {

if (!_actionSheet) {

_actionSheetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 373, 320, 403);
_actionSheetBtnFrameOk = CGRectMake(20, 330, 280, 50);
_actionSheetBtnFreameCancel = CGRectMake(20, 275, 280, 50);
_pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 216);


    _actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    _datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    [_datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

    [_actionSheet addSubview:_datePicker];
}

[_datePicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];

[_actionSheet showInView:self.view.superview];
[[[_actionSheet subviews] objectAtIndex:kActionBtnIndexOk] setFrame:_actionSheetBtnFrameOk];
[[[_actionSheet subviews] objectAtIndex:kActionBtnIndexCancel] setFrame:_actionSheetBtnFreameCancel];

[_actionSheet setFrame:_actionSheetFrame];
[_datePicker setFrame:_pickerFrame];
```

}

You will also have to implement the UIActionSheetDelegate method to set the button's text once the user has selected his desired date.

```
#pragma mark - UIActionSheet Delegate Methods

- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [self.myTodayButton setTitle:self.dateStringFromSelectedDate forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: THank you so much benny!!  That got rid of my error however the title of the button hasnt changed.  Is my code correct if I want to change the displayed text of the button, myTodayButton?    [_myTodayButton setTitle:dateStringForInput forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }

Comment: Your code seems good Michael, there are two possible issues. One you have not linked the actual button to the variable that represents it in code i.e. myTodayButton. Open the Storyboard or XIB file and control drag from the UIViewController icon in the dock to the button and let go, you should then be able to link the button to the property called myTodayButton. If you already did this then maybe the string you are passing in is nil? Put a break in the method and check what value dateStringForInput is, it might be nil?!

Comment: Thanks again, I think I just realized what my problem is...totally different topic so I should probably create a new post but maybe you can shed some light.  I have scene 1 which has the "Today" button, when you hit that button it segues to scene 2 which contains the date picker and another button which turns that date into a string, sends it to scene 1 and is supposed to change the text of the button, however when i hit the button on scene 2 it segues back to scene 1 which appears to be reset to when the app first loads...is there way to segue to scene2 and back to scene 1 without reloading?

Comment: basically i want to pause scene 1, jump to scene 2 and return back to scene 1 with a new date value.

Comment: I edited my answer for this. Its formatting is a little messed up but I think you will get the idea. Good luck!

Comment: if you think that using an actionSheet is more efficient and in general a better way to work things i would love to see that code if you dont mind.  As i mentioned I am a new programmer so I want to learn the best ways to accomplish things.    thanks again for all your help. you are helping me preserve my sanity here.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Class methods do not have access to instance variables, that's why you're getting the error you're seeing.

You need to change the method to an instance method:

```
- (void)changeButtonText:(NSString *)dateStringForInput;
```

Then you will need to pass or obtain a reference to the *instance* of the class containing the  method to the class calling the method.

I hope that makes sense... Add a comment if you need any clarification!