# how to access a method from an other class WITHOUT creating object in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

Is there a way to access a method from an other class without creating an object in Objective-C?

Comment: Yes, class methods? You add `+` instead of `-` infront of method declarations and then you can invoke it like `[MyClass myMethod];`

Comment: How is it? could u tell about it ?

Comment: Google class methods in objective c. They are methods that belong to the class instance rather then an object of a particular class.

Comment: you should give NSNotificationCenter a try: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you are really looking for class methods; Objective-C's equivalent to other languages' `static` methods. See: [What is the difference between class and instance methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)

To define one:

```
@implementation MONObject
+ (void)classMethod { ... }
@end
```

In use: `[MONObject classMethod]`

---

If you want the instance method as a callable C function, see `class_getInstanceMethod`, or simply `IMP imp = [MONClass instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(someSelector)];`.

Answer (score 8):

```
@interface APotentiallyBadIdea : NSObject

+ (void)potentiallySillyUnmooredMethod:(NSString *)string;

@end


@implementation APotentiallyBadIdea

+ (void)potentiallySillyUnmooredMethod:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"ask yourself why this isn't on a real object %@", string);
}

@end
```

Call it like this:

```
[APotentiallyBadIdea potentiallySillyUnmooredMethod:@"this might be ok if it's part of a more complete object implementation"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use + sign to define the method which would make it static method, accessible via class name like this

in .h file

```
+ (void) someMethod;
```

in .m file

```
+ (void) someMethod {}
```

than you can easily access it via class name in another file

```
[ClassName someMethod];
```

Note: don't forget to import that class.

Comment: There's no such thing as a static method in Objective-C. Methods prefixed with a `+` are class methods, which is something entirely different.