# When do I use a + or - at the beginning of creating a method?

Tags: objective-c

Can someone explain to me the situation when writing these and the difference?

```
 - (id) startsWithMinus:(NSString *)title;
```

or

```
 + (id) startsWithPlus:(NSString *)title;
```

Comment: @rjstelling possibly not, if the question is exactly other way round?

Comment: I can't imagine this isn't in any beginner Objective-C tutorial. -1 for having shown no research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been indicated here the + indicates a class method, and the - indicates an instance method.

The important difference that will likely be relevant to your programming is when to use a class versus and instance method.  A class method (+) is simply a method you call using the class.  So, something along the lines of [[DataAccess class] getInfoFromServer].  You would want to use a class method when you do not need to access properties but want specific behavior that is related to the class (for example, it makes sense to be calling a DataAccess class to grab information from a server.)

Alternatively, you would want to use an instance method when you want to alloc and initialize an object and then use its properties.  So for example, DataAccess * accessObject = [[DataAccess alloc] init] would give you a DataAccess object.  That object would presumably have relevant properties which would be declared in the @interface either in your .h file or .m file.

For example, going along with the DataAccess class you would have something like this declared in your .m file before the @implementation.

```
 @interface DataAccess()
 @property (strong, non-atomic) NSDictionary * data;

 @end
```

Then in any given instance method you can assume that the object has data set.  So you can use calls like self.data in the instance method to grab the data because you assume for the object calling the method the property data has been set.  If you use a class method, you cannot make a call to self.data because you are not working with a particular instance of the method.

To put it perhaps over-simply, you can think of class methods as simple functions related to the class where you do not need to access particular properties of an instance of the class, whereas you can think of instance methods as needing an instance of the class to call it, since it needs properties associated with an instance (an allocated object of the class) to work properly.

Comment: Thank you! This was immensely helpful. I knew the class vs instance method, but when reading up on it could not really understand the situations until you explained it like that.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with `+` means that you are declaring a class method.
Starting with `-` means that you are declaring an instance method.

If you aren't familiar with these terms then you should see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-methods) for an explanation.

Comment: Good answer. Concise and provides further reading.

Answer (score -1):

`+` stands for a class method, while `-` stands for a instance method