# IOS NSMethodSignature stays nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsinvocation

I recently started to develop for IOS and struggle with the Invocation Object.

What i have is a Class "Location", derived from NSManagedObject (it's part of the Coredata model)

```
@interface Location (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addHasLocationInfoObject:(Info *)value;
...
@end
```

I also have other Classes that have similar signatures (addHasWorkorderInfoObject,...).

These InfoObjects have constraints with their "parent objects" in this case "Location" has several "LocationInfo" Objects, which i retrieve from a Database and want to add to the Location. Same thing should happen to all Objects that have InfoObjects assigned.

I am now trying to create a method that will work for any Object that sticks to the naming-conventions fixed by the project-documentation (Location -> addHasLocationInfoObject, XY -> addHasXYInfoObject ...).

My Approach for adding Infos to Objects now is:

```
-(void)setInfoForObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject withClass:(NSString *)className 
NSString *noteRefName = [[NSString alloc]init];
noteRefName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Info", className];
NSString *addInfoSelectorName = [[NSString alloc]init];
addInfoSelectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addHas%@Object::", infoClassName];

SEL addInfoPropertySelector = NSSelectorFromString(addInfoSelectorName);
NSMethodSignature *signature  = [[managedObject class] methodSignatureForSelector:addNotePropertySelector];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];

[invocation setTarget:managedObject];
[invocation setSelector:addInfoPropertySelector];
[invocation setArgument:&note   atIndex:2];
```

However this gives me an Error, because the Signature object gets set to nil. I tried searching for the Problem and it seems to be related to the ":" in the Selectors' name.

But I do not understand how many and where and why i have to set these? I also seem to fail to find the Docs page that tells me how to do it properly.

Anny help appreciated, Thanks in advance!

PS. I Logged the SelectorName and the Classname and they both are spelled correctly.

Comment: not sure i understand why you put two "::" in a method name, while there's only one in a method signature?

Comment: because it neither worked without : nor with one :, so i gave it a shot^^

Comment: NSLog the generated selector name.  ("addHas(null)Object:" is not a valid selector name, eg.)

Comment: "Location - addHasLocationInfoObject:" if i log className - selectorName

Comment: Why not use `-performSelector:withObject:` using `NSSelectorFromString`?

Comment: You should also send `methodSignatureForSelector:` to `managedObject` rather than to its `class`.

Comment: performSelector and clearing the core data stuff did the Trick, if you put it in an answer i can give you the credit for it^^

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I see multiple problems in your code. First of all, you allocate empty string instances and then immediately re-write them with new instances:

```
NSString *noteRefName = [[NSString alloc]init];
noteRefName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Info", className];
```

This is wrong. Correct way is:

```
NSString *noteRefName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Info", className];
```

There are two types of methods in ObjC: class methods and instance methods. If you don't know the difference, read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-methods). So, the second problem is that you are trying to get a class method signature with `methodSignatureForSelector:` instead of getting instance method signature with `instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:`.

So, as far as I can tell, the correct way of re-writing this piece of code could be:

```
NSString *addInfoSelectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addHas%@Object:", infoClassName];
...
NSMethodSignature *signature = [[managedObject class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:addNotePropertySelector];
```

Comment: i corrected the instanciating empty objects, but your fix leads to the same error

Comment: then, I guess, managedObject is wrong. I've just created a test project and it works fine for me.

Comment: NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [managedObject class], addNoteSelectorName]); Logs correct values "Location - addHasLocationInfoObject"

Comment: add the following log:     NSLog(@"%d", [managedObject respondsToSelector:addInfoPropertySelector]);

Comment: respondsToSelector Logs: "1"

Comment: why "addHasLocationInfoObject" in your output is without a colon?

Comment: You should just write `[managedObject methodSignatureForSelector:addNotePropertySelector]` instead of `[[managedObject class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:addNotePropertySelector]`