# Refactoring ViewController code to move method that returns UIImage into a relevant subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage

I have created a method already that returns a UIImage as follows:

```
- (UIImage *)circularOverlayMask
{
    // Constants
    CGRect rect = self.navigationController.view.bounds;
    CGFloat width = rect.size.width;
    CGFloat height = rect.size.height;

    CGFloat diameter = width-(kInnerEdgeInset*2);
    CGFloat radius = diameter/2;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(width/2, height/2);
    UIColor *fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5];

    // Create the image context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);

    // Create the bezier paths
    UIBezierPath *clipPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(center.x-radius, center.y-radius, diameter, diameter)];

    [clipPath appendPath:maskPath];
    clipPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;

    [clipPath addClip];
    [fillColor setFill];
    [clipPath fill];

    UIImage *_maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return _maskedImage;
}
```

This works as expected and is currently in my View Controller code. I am trying to better refactor the code for the view controller and would like to move this to an appropriate subclass.

My initial thoughts were to subclass `UIImage` and return the image somehow. Another thought was to subclass `UIImageView` and within the `init` method call `initWithImage` then `[self circularOverlayMask];`. Another thought would be to simply subclass `NSObject` and add the method, then import where needed and call a public `+` method.

**Question**
What is the correct approach to refactoring this simple method into a relevant subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of subclass, I would write a category of `UIImage` with this method. So to use it you would have to import your category:

```
#import "UIImage+Masks.h"
```

And then you can just call it from `UIImage`:

```
[UIImage circularOverlayMaskForRect:]
```

Comment: The method would have to take the view bounds as a parameter, for example `circularOverlayMaskForRect:`.

Comment: @MartinR That is correct, thanks. I was just whipping up a quick example.

Comment: Thanks both, I have completed the above but when I call `UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage circularOverlayMaskForRect:self.view.bounds];` I get an error no known class method for selector `circular...`? How should this be called. I have imported the header as normal

Comment: @StuartM of course you should write the actual category class first ;) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: I have written the category already if that is what you mean. I didn't just try to import a category that didn't exist it wouldn't build would it ;)

Comment: @StuartM Hmm, did you declare the method in the .h file of your category?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo - I had to create the image first `UIImage *newImage = [UIImage new];` then call the method on that `[newImage circularOverLayMaskForRect:self.view];` is this correct? I thought with a category I could call it in the same way your answer suggests?

Comment: @StuartM It depends, if you declared the method as an instance method (with a + sign instead of - sign), you can call it like my example. It's the same with all Obj-C classes, not only category. But I assume now you have successfully written this category?

Comment: *sorry, the one with the + sign is called class method, not instance method.

Comment: Yes thanks, I will update this to be a class method instead (+). I guess there is no issue here if this is a class/instance method

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo - is there no issue here if this is a class/instance method?

Comment: @StuartM In this particular case, I think it's ok. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1053722/361247