# How to make buttons that go to a different screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, screen

Hey I'm having a lot of trouble with this idea I have. How do I make buttons that go to a different screen but on the CODE?

Basically depending on a value that may or may not be different for every user (Let's say the value is in x already) it will make a list of buttons...

When you click the list of buttons, they each individually go to a different screen.

How do I do this? I know how to on storyboard.. but code wise?

Edit: I SHOULD note that for the buttons specifically I have this and it is working in the code (didn't use storyboard):

```
        UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(50, 200, 200, 50);
        [btn setTitle:@"Button 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: Do not put tags in the title and use proper tags for your question. This is Objective-C code, not C code. And the "new" tag clearly states not to use it.

Comment: yeah i know this is objective c code and not c, but stackoverflow told me i couldn't use the word objective. ah well.

Comment: your question is you have a list of buttons and on clicking those buttons depending on button clicked it hold go to respective screen?

Comment: Based on what a value is (can be 4000 different values - depending on what user inputs) <-- i already have the code so the value is a variable. It will create a list of buttons and upon clicking those buttons they each will link to their respective screen.

Answer (score 0):

First add a target to your button:

```
  //Add target to your button, to call a method that presents the next ViewController:
    UIButton *yourButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToNextPageMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

User one of the two, case you are using a UINavigation controller or not, place them in the method you are calling when the button is pressed (the target)

```
    //Normal presentation
    YourViewController *vc = [[YourViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    //Navgiation bar
    YourViewController *vc = [[YourViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an action to your button by doing the following:

```
UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(50, 200, 200, 50);
[btn setTitle:@"Button 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

and then in your someAction method, you push the view modally or via your navigation controller

```
- (void)someAction
{
    //init your view controller here....
    YourViewController *vc = [[YourViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: But how do I put in the someAction method to go to a new screen? and how do I decide what goes there in the code (Not using storyboard) ?

Comment: in the someAction method you basically init a new viewcontroller which is the "screen" you want to show (see @PiratM 's answer on how to do this). And then you push that new viewcontroller. Edited my answer to include the someAction method - hope that helps.

Comment: It does actually. Thank you a lot. I know you're going to think this is a really dumb question but it would help me a lot. What's the difference between a - and a + before the (void)? In the default code they use +... and also the compiler is stating someAction is undeclared.. how do I declare it? Thank you so much!

Comment: glad that it helps! the + is a class method and - is an instance method. I think this post answers it very well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-methods

Comment: The above code seems to be fine for me. Make sure the selector is not someAction: and it is someAction

Comment: Thanks Mike, but I still am receiving the error of use of undeclared identifer ???? The selector being undeclared is actually something common in iOS and I just disabled it but for the void well thats what it's saying.. its undeclared.