# How to make button that will go to a different screen in Objective C without storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, screen

I have this so far:

```
        UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(50, 200, 200, 50);
        [btn setTitle:@"Button 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Now I have someAction.. where do I put it and how do I do this? I'm sorry.. I hate asking questions.. but I looked over this everywhere and spent hours..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make buttons that go to a different screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647811/how-to-make-buttons-that-go-to-a-different-screen)

Comment: Please do not repost your questions. If needed, update your other question with additional details.

Comment: Alright man. Can you help me ? I keep on getting undeclared identifier and I've literally searched everywhere. Look at the comment below.

Comment: If you're getting an error message, you need to post the actual message, not paraphrase. We can't help you if we don't know what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboards, and created a `push` segue, then the code looks like this

```
- (void)someAction
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SomeSegueName" sender:nil];
}
```

If you're using storyboards, but don't have a segue, then the code looks like this

```
- (void)someAction
{
    MyViewController *vc;

    vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

If you aren't using storyboards at all, then I expect your head will eventually start hurting from banging it against the wall.

Comment: I am using storyboards. Do I put that void on the bottom of the code i wrote in my original post?

Comment: .. because I'm getting "use of undeclared identifier 'someAction'

Comment: Yes, that code goes in the same file as the code you posted.

Comment: What do i do about the undeclared identifier ?

Comment: I don't know why you're getting that. The compiler usually doesn't complain about things that are inside an `@selector`. Are you sure that's the only place `someAction` is used?

Comment: The compiler is complaining about the first line:         - (void)someAction
        {
            MyViewController *vc;
            
            vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeVC"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        }

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'someAction'

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from your question into a method called `- (void)test`. No warnings or errors, but it crashes at runtime since the `someAction` method isn't defined.  Added the `someAction` method from my post.  No warnings or errors. No crash.  If you need help finding the source of the error, you need to post your code.