# Objective-C Syntax for Messages

Tags: objective-c

For this line of code:

```
NSHost *now = [NSHost currentHost];
```

Why is it that the method, currentHost, returns a pointer to NSHost and not to currentHost?

Answer (score 0):

It is a class method:

> Returns an NSHost object representing the host the process is running on.

That is what the method was designed it do.

Answer (score 0):

The method does *not* return a pointer to `NSHost`, what is a type and class object, but to an instance object of the class `NSHost`. This instance object *is* the current host.

(`int *` is not a pointer to `int`, but a pointer to a C object of the type `int`.)

Answer (score -1):

NSHost is a class name and currentHost is a static method of that class. So all objects of type NSHost share one currentHost. For example you can check the `self` value gainst NSHost to see if your object is the currentHost or something else.

Comment: Actually a class method, not a static method.

Comment: So would this be similar to how polymorphism is implemented?

Comment: @zaph thats largely a synonym. I can't tell the difference, but it seems that the idea of class methods is nearer to the idea of interfaces, while static methods are more a part of a class definition.

Comment: In Objective-C classes really do have class methods. One class method can call another class method of the same class with self. They must be called with a reference to the class, not an instance of the class. See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1053646/451475) and this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW18)

Comment: @zaph an instance method has the same distance to a class method as to a static method. It's just another name. But for objective-c the name class method might be preferred. I don't really care.

Comment: Class methods are part of the class, they support inheritance, can and are subclassed. Look at NSObject class methods, these methods are commonaly subclassed. (Oh, I'm not the down vote).