# How to call alert function from another controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alert

I have a OnePresence.swift file and on it I have:

```
extension OnePresence: XMPPStreamDelegate {
    public func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream, didReceivePresence presence: XMPPPresence) {
        OpenChatsTableViewController().showAlert(username)
    }
}
```

In my OpenChatsTableViewController:

```
func showAlert(username: String) {
    showBuddyRequest(username)
}
```

And where:

```
import Foundation

protocol BuddyRequestProtocol {
    func showBuddyRequest(fromUser: String)
}

extension BuddyRequestProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func showBuddyRequest(fromUser: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "AAA", message: "\(fromUser) wants to add you as a friend.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Friend Request", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

in this case I get the next error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7c3c4400> on <OpenChatsTableViewController: 0x7b0ecee0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

How can I fix this code and rewrite/refactor it?

Answer (score -1):

Your `OpenChatsTableViewController` is not shown, so it cannot present the alert. You first have to make sure the `OpenChatsTableViewController` is in view (eg by pushing it on the navigation stack) before trying to show the alert.

Comment: Apparently you make a new one (see the brackets "()") - you have to take the one you are showing

Comment: So, how need I use it? Can you help me with it? When I try without brackets it gives me error

Comment: Of course, it's the CLASS you are using, not the instance. Somewhere you create the `OpenChatsTableViewController` when you show it - you have to keep a reference to that instance, and use that one for displaying your alert. If you don't know what I'm talking about, please read up on classes and instances (eg here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-methods)

Comment: I tried this: `var a = OpenChatsTableViewController()` before the class I defined it, later I tried to use: `a.showAlert()` but it shows that OpenChats doesn't have such method

Comment: Okay, I fixed this error, too, but it still returns me hierarchy error