# Java Singleton Sometimes Throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, singleton

Im coming to Java from other languages, so please forgive me if this is obvious, but I've encountered a very strange behavior.

I'm writing a simple Pig UDF. I'm returning a Tuple object, which I create using a TupleFactory singleton. In the following two code examples, the first example works, while the second throws a NullPointerException when creating the `newTuple`;

```
public class MyUDF {

    public Tuple func(Tuple input) {
        return TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(Arrays.asList(o1, o2, o3));
    }
}

public class MyUDF {
    ...
    TupleFactory _factory;

    public Tuple func(Tuple input) {
        _factory.getInstance();
        return _factory.newTuple(Arrays.asList(o1, o2, o3));
    }
}
```

Comment: that bcz you are operating on _factory.getInstance() returns a new instance which is not assigned back to _factory instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code `TupleFactory.getInstance()` is calling a static class method on the class itself, as might be expected for a Singleton pattern implementation.

## Calling instance method without an instance

Your second code `_factory.getInstance()` is calling on an instance variable, a class member which is defined but not yet instantiated. You cannot call an object method on an object that does not exist.

## `Enum` as Singleton

Lastly, the best safest simplest way to implement the Singleton pattern in Java is through an enum. Search Stack Overflow and/or a search-engine for words such as : Java singleton enum Joshua Bloch "Effective Java".

```
public enum TupleFactory {
    INSTANCE;

    // Add private constructor if needed.

    public Tuple makeTuple( … ) {
        …
        return tuple ;
    }

}
```

Using this is simple.

```
Tuple t = TupleFactory.INSTANCE.makeTuple( … ) ;
```

## Beware of misuse of Singleton

Lastly, I'll add the obligatory caution about *Singleton* often being a “code smell”, a symptom of poor design stemming from a lack of understanding of Object-Oriented Programming.

Answer (score 0):

you have to store   _factory.getInstance(); output first
as
Tupleinstanceclass obj=  _factory.getInstance();
return obj.newTuple(Arrays.asList(o1, o2, o3));

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change to

```
public class MyUDF {
...
TupleFactory _factory;

public Tuple func(Tuple input) {
    _factory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
    return _factory.newTuple(Arrays.asList(o1, o2, o3));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your first piece of code, I can infer that the `getInstance()` method is `static`. The important point to note about `static` methods is that you shouldn't access them using Class objects. Instead, you should access them using Class name because they're class methods.

The basic idea behind using `singletons` is that you initially don't have the object of the class and you're calling a class method (*not an instance method*) to get the object of that class. Now your first piece of code justifies it but in second part of code, you already have `_factory` object, so why would you call `getInstance()` to get the object of the class.

Also in this line `_factory.getInstance()`, note that `_factory` have just been declared but was never initialized, and that's the reason why you're getting `NullPointerException`.

Also see :

1. [What is the difference between class and instance methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053592/2815219)
2. [Java: when to use static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2671496/2815219)

---

The following code will work.

```
public class MyUDF {
    TupleFactory _factory;

    public Tuple func(Tuple input) {
        _factory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
        return _factory.newTuple(Arrays.asList(o1, o2, o3));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe your statement "you can't access them using Class objects" should be changed to "you should not access them using Class objects"