# Concept of constant property during initialization in Swift

Tags: swift, properties, initialization

***“
For class instances, a constant property can be modified during initialization only by the class that introduces it. It cannot be modified by a subclass.”
Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.1).” iBooks.***

I am having difficulty in understanding this, Since i am able to modify the property by a subclass also.
Below is the code.

```
class ConstantTest {
    let constant: String
    init(constant: String) {
        self.constant = constant
    }
    func printConstant() {
        print(constant)
    }
}

let constanttest = ConstantTest(constant: "Hello")
constanttest.printConstant()

class SubConstClass: ConstantTest { }

var subTest = SubConstClass(constant: "hey")
subTest.printConstant()
```

Comment: This subclass doesn't modify the value. The `init` is in the superclass. (Note that classes should have a leading capital; it's difficult to read your example.)

Comment: @RobNapier Sorry for the trouble,

Answer (score 4):

The key to your confusion is what it means for a subclass to initialize a constant property. This means that a subclass cannot *introduce* an initializer that assigns the value. Let's consider a simple case:

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    init() {
        name = "Alice"
    }
}
```

This could be more simply written by assigning `name` in its declaration, but I'm hoping this is clearer. Now we want to create a subclass that assigns `name` to something else. The obvious way to do this (and how you'd do it in languages that don't have constant properties) would be to assign it after calling `super.init()`:

```
class Employee: Person {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        name = "Bob" // error: cannot assign to property: 'name' is a 'let' constant
    }
}
```

Nope. We run into exactly the case described in your excerpt. Well, maybe we should assign it first?

```
class Employee: Person {
    override init() {
        name = "Bob" // error: cannot assign to property: 'name' is a 'let' constant
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Nope. No better.

Ah! It's because we call `super.init()`. Let's just not call it.

```
class Employee: Person {
    override init() {
        name = "Bob" // error: cannot assign to property: 'name' is a 'let' constant
    }
}
```

No... When they say you can't do this, they mean you can't do this. You can explore more, for instance changing the class to:

```
class Person {
    let name = "Alice"
}
```

And you'll find you have all the same problems. You cannot assign to a `let` constant in a superclass from a method introduced in a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You are not modifying existing constants in your code - only creating new instances of your class.  If you want to see an error to prove it, try this:

```
let constanttest = ConstantTest(constant: "Hello")
constanttest.constant = "World" //Will not compile because "constant" is a constant
```

As an example for the bit about it not being able to be modified by a subclass:

```
class ConstantTest {

    let constant: String //<--- This is the constant you are unable to change
    init(constant: String) {
        self.constant = constant
    }

    func printConstant() {
        print(constant)
    }
}

let constantTest = ConstantTest(constant: "Hello")
constantTest.printConstant()
constantTest.constant = "World" //Will not compile

class SubConstClass: ConstantTest { }

let subTest = SubConstClass(constant: "hey")
subTest.printConstant()
subTest.constant = "Hi" //Will not compile (same as superclass)
```

In case you are confused about the instantiation of these classes, here is another simple example of `var` and `let` using `String`:

```
let constantString = "constant"
var mutableString = "mutable"

constantString = "oops" //Will not compile
mutableString = "changed" //Totally fine, since this is a var
```

Comment: I changed the let constant to var and tried running the below code, it ran successfully and even i was able to modify the property with subclass also.       please find the example below :-

Comment: Again, you are not modifying properties in your code - you are simply creating new `ConstantTest` instances.  These are the same _type_, but are different instances.  As for the subclass - same thing.  You are creating a new instance of the subclass, and are never modifying any properties once they are initialized.

Comment: i am very sorry, i am not able to paste my code properly

Comment: It's ok - I can see what you're doing.  I think you're still misunderstanding though - now you have made `constant` a `var` instead of a `let`.  That means that is is _not_ a constant, so you are able to modify it, which is why you're able to set it to "Hii".  If you create a constant with `let` it means that you can't assign a new value to that constant.

Comment: ohh my mistake, is it possible to explain ("For class instances, a constant property can be modified during initialization only by the class that introduces it. It cannot be modified by a subclass.") via example.

Comment: I added more examples.  Hopefully this helps?

Answer (score 1):

I just think the other answer haven't understood your confusion. , though creeperspeak commented you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796339/concept-of-constant-property-during-initialization-in-swift#comment72708479_42796608). You seem not to understand the difference between a **class** and its **instances**:

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16435532/5175709) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37778160/5175709)

And then the examples below:

```
let constanttest1 = ConstantTest(constant: "Hello") // This is an INSTANCE of ConstantTest class
let constanttest2 = ConstantTest(constant: "Hi") // ANOTHHER INSTANCE
let constanttest3 = ConstantTest(constant: "Bye") // another instance
let constanttest4 = ConstantTest(constant: "ByeBye") // another instance

var subTest = SubConstClass(constant: "hey") // This is an an instance of SubConstClass
var subTest2 = SubConstClass(constant: "heyhey") // This is an an instance of SubConstClass
var subTest3 = SubConstClass(constant: "HaHaHa") // This is an an instance of SubConstClass.
```

None of the instances conflict with each other.