# Difference between instantiating a class and calling a callable class function

Tags: dart

The Dart docs say that the 'new' operator is optional when instantiating an object from a class.
It also says you can define a class to be a callable function by defining a Call() function within the class.

Given a class

```
Class MyClass
```

And i define both a constructor and Call() function within that class (neither of which has been defined to take any arguments)

what would the value of somevar be?

```
dynamic somevar = MyClass();
```

Would it be an instance of MyClass or would it be the return value of the Call() function?

Comment: check this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-methods#:~:text=Like%20the%20other%20answers%20have,instance%20in%20as%20a%20parameter).`

Comment: Nope, i don't see how this is relevant at all. My issue isn't understanding the difference between a callable class and a constructor. My issue is that it seems to me that the instantiation of a class and the calling of a callable class seems to have the exact same syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#callable-classes) calls them "callable classes", but that's a misnomer.  They're callable objects.

Typically `call()` is a *method* on an *instance* of the class, not on the class itself. `MyClass()` would always invoke the unnamed constructor of `MyClass`.

More concretely:

```dart
class MyClass {
  void call() {
    print('Hello world!');
  }
}

void main() {
  var object = MyClass(); // Invokes the (implicit) unnamed MyClass constructor.
  object(); // Invokes the call() method.
}
```